# Why when loading page inside another using ajax the parent posts back to the sub page?

Tags: asp.net, jquery

I'm loading page inside div in another page..the problem is when I press LinkButton in the parent page to do postback, the postback goes to the sub page not to the parent one.

I'm using jQuery ajax to load the page:

```
$('#myDiv').html(refreshingDiv).load('subPagePath.aspx');
```

How do I solve this problem ?

Comment: `the postback goes to the sub page...`; what does that mean?

Answer (score 0):

You should not load the whole ASPX Page into the DIV because when you make a AJAX request to get an ASPX page from the server and load it into the DIV, actually some parameters like ViewState of the main page gets overwritten. Accordingly  the ViewState will gets corrupted however if you load a HTML Page into a DIV, you can see it will be working fine.

So, Instead get the Data in the JSON Format and load in into the DIV accordingly

Hope it answers your question!!